# What does the "E" mean in a XAMPP 403 load error?

Tags: javascript, xampp, load

Setting up a website on XAMPP, and getting a 403 file-load error. What does the "E" after the `%` mean in the console error message below? (It also shows up when I `GET` the page with ctrl-F5.

"js/TF4UI.js%3E Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)"

Comment: check this link http://www.javascripter.net/faq/escape-encodeuri-lower-ascii.htm %3E is '>' uri encoded

Comment: %3E is the urlencoded form of the `>` character.

Comment: @Karthik Ganesan Thanks! What... do you think it might it be doing there?

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks! Any idea what it's doing there?